# Help with meaning of symbols on switch for electrical blinds

Tags: wiring

I have a difficulty of understanding what is the meaning of these symbols on the back of my switch for electrical blinds? I know that the symbol is for the switch but have a hard time understanding what does the "extra quarter of the circle" is for?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've posted an answer for this; would you let me know if the blinds actually  function the way I  suggested? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "L" is common, and the other two are momentary-closed when you push the up or down button. There's nothing more than that; the circle doesn't mean anything.

Each terminal provides two holes to attach wires, if you're wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "L" is actually a clock icon, indicating a time delay:

[image]

Here's my interpretation: on the left you can see a switch that, when closed, raises the blinds (the up-arrow on the top left). That switch then triggers a time delay which, when done, allows a switch on the right to lower the blinds (the down-arrow at the bottom center).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a normally open time delay to close switch